# Async execution of php-script is working with authenticated session

Tags: php, linux, asynchronous, apache

I am trying to run a script asynchronously. There is no problem finding out how to do that on Stackoverflow. The problem is that I am trying one of the examples I found but it's not working. The scripts runs without outputing errors in the error_log though.

**My main-php script:**

```
function backgroundPost($url){

    $parts=parse_url($url);

      $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],
              isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80,
              $errno, $errstr, 30);


      if (!$fp) {
          return false;
      } else {
          $out = "POST ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
          $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
          $out.= "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
          $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($parts['query'])."\r\n";
          $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($parts['query'])."\r\n";
          $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
          if (isset($parts['query'])) $out.= $parts['query'];

          fwrite($fp, $out);

          fclose($fp);

          return true;
      }
    }

    //Example of use
    backgroundPost('http://192.168.1.107/smic/testarea/runner.php?id=1');
```

Response from fwrite() is "155".

backgroundPost is returning 'true'.

**runner.php:**

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(50);
error_log("RUNNING!");
```

How come "RUNNING! is note written to error log? It's like the scipt isn't actually executed.

When accessing runner.php directly (with the URL posted in backgroundPost) the script works as expected.

Both scripts has privilege 777 for apache:apache.

Running on

- Linux/CentOS 6.2
- PHP 5.3.3
- Apache 2.2.15

Could it be related to that I am using a authenticated session and the user that is authenticated is not, of course, apache who is the one running the scripts?

**Test with CURL**

Suggested by @jprofitt I did try curl as well:

**async_curl.php:**

```
$ch = curl_init("http://192.168.1.107/");
$fp = fopen("http://192.168.1.107/smic/testarea/runner.php", "r");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "kaand:xIWGWt0DNVriw"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo print_r($info);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Tis is printed from curl_getinfo($ch):

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://192.168.1.107/
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [http_code] => 302
    [header_size] => 411
    [request_size] => 103
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.002165
    [namelookup_time] => 0.000106
    [connect_time] => 0.000192
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.000211
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.002109
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] => http://192.168.1.107/login.php
)
1
```

I did try with $ch = curl_init("http://192.168.1.107/"); as well, then I got message "Authorization Required" on my web. In the error_log I get HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization required for running.php.

I do also get complaints in the error_log that $fp "is not a valid File-Handle resource" when doing 'curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);'.

There is a re-direct to a login page at the end of the array, could this be related to that problem?

Comment: What is  `backgroundPost()` returning?

Comment: It's returning 'true' ('1' when echo backgroundPost()).

Comment: Have you tried to use `curl` instead?

Comment: No I haven't, since this is supposed to work I just assumed that I have done something wrong. Rigth now I am trying to figure out if it has something to do with security (I use authenticated session).

Comment: `curl` makes it pretty easy to POST something. Perhaps give that a try to see if it's an issue with the connection. You could also try having your runner.php write a file in its directory to see if this is just an issue with `error_log()`.

Comment: Ok I tried with curl. I updated my post, the second half is related to curl now. There certainly is som kind of authentication problem. But I did send the login credentials so I'm still puzzled how to solve it.

Comment: If you remove the authentication requirement from runner.php does it work? Maybe also try opening your `$fp` with read and write instead of just read (this one is just speculation, though)

Comment: Tried that now, removing the security constraints and that information from curl made it work. I also skipped the fopen-part and instead defined the url using CURLOPT_URL parameter in curl_setup(,,) as well as have no paramters in the curl_ini(). Now it works. So links should be fine. But still, I don't know how to get this working when having authentication restrictions.

Comment: And while at it, I did add the authentication again and now it works. In some way I assume that it was the fopen part who broke this as well. Thanks for the help @jprofitt, I would like to check "answer" but it's a bit difficult in this "comment-chat".

Comment: (You could copy my solution crate an answer, it's in the post).

Comment: Go ahead and write out a good answer for the Future People and then mark it as solved! All I did was blindly point ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem I had was related to the restricted area of runner.php. Whether I use curl or fsockopen I need to authenticate the request. Here I include the solution for both fsockopen and curl doing asynchronous request for restricted areas.

**fsockopen:**

```
function backgroundPost($url){        

    $parts=parse_url($url);
    echo $parts['path']."<br/>"; 
    echo $parts['host']."<br/>"; 
    echo $url;

  $fp = fsockopen($parts['host'],  
          isset($parts['port'])?$parts['port']:80,
          $errno, $errstr, 10);

 $auth = base64_encode("kaand:kaand123");
  if (!$fp) {
      return false;
  } else {
      $out = "POST ".$parts['path']." HTTP/1.1\r\n";
      $out.= "Host: ".$parts['host']."\r\n";
      $out.= "User-Agent: Anonymous\r\n";
      $out.= "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n";
      $out.= "Authorization: Basic ".$auth;
      $out.= "Content-Length: ".strlen($parts['query'])."\r\n";
      $out.= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
      if (isset($parts['query'])) $out.= $parts['query'];

      fwrite($fp, $out);

      fclose($fp);

      return true;
  }
}
```

Example of use:

```
backgroundPost('http://192.168.1.107/smic/testarea/runner.php?id=1');
```

**curl:**

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://192.168.1.107/smic/testarea/runner.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC ) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "kaand:kaand123"); //Don't use the sha1-value
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**runner.php**

```
do whatever...
```

I think I'll go for the fsockopen, think it's a nicer solution than having time-outs which force you to have at least some waiting time. If there will be a lot of traffic even 1 second can build up...